# How to find latest equal element in two linked lists?

Tags: algorithm, search, linked-list, tail

There is two [linked lists](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linked_list). They have common tail. I want to find latest element, which is the same in both lists.

For example,

`List1` is 10->4->5->*2*->**9**->53->64->345->23

`List2` is 10->4->5->*2*->**8**->53->64->345->23->43->53

I want to find 2.

We can iterate over list in `O(n)`.

Is there a better way to find needed element, than in `O(min(n, m))`?

Comment: The only way to traverse a linked list is O(n), so I can't see any algorithm working better than O(n + m).

Comment: `O(n + m)` is a obvious answer. I hope, that there is better solution...

Comment: Well, I guess strictly the answer is O(min(m, n)) for the most obvious algorithm.

Comment: @Phylogenesis, yeah, you are right. I made a mistake with an estimate of the time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
node1 = list1head
node2 = list2head
ans = {error}
while(node1 && node2 && node1.data == node2.data)
  ans = node1.data
  node1 = node1.next
  node2 = node2.next
end while
return ans
```

`Cost = O(min(m, n))`

Comment: thank you for answer. It is a correct solution, but I hope, that may be there something, that is more better, that this algorithm.

Comment: For a singly linked list, you can not traverse any faster than this.